# How Gaurav's action in the end justified?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, fan

*[Fan (2016)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_(film))* is a thriller featuring [Shahrukh Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shah_Rukh_Khan) in dual role.

Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_(film)) page of the film,

> Gaurav Chandna (Shah Rukh Khan) is a Delhi-based die-hard and obsessive fan of Bollywood superstar Aryan Khanna (also Shah Rukh Khan); Aryan is Gaurav's whole life. Gaurav's face bears an uncanny similarity to Aryan's, which helps him win the local talent show competition.

But as the film progresses, things change and many things happen. In the end, Gaurav jumps off from the top of the building and commits suicide because he was not apologised. He doesn't listen to the words of Aryan Khanna to think about his parents and rest of the life. He replies:

> **Tu nahi samjhega**.
>
> Translation:  You will never understand.

How is this suicide of Gaurav Chandna justified?

<sup>As a side note, there are many people who believe that Gaurav is not dead but injured due to fall from height because he is shown in the end of the movie.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

From Gaurav's perspective, his life revolves around Aryan only. He worships/respects Aryan. Aryan was center of his life and everything else doesn't matter much without him. When Aryan ignores him and wants him to live his life without interfering with Aryan, he lost that.

If you are looking for justification from our perspective, then it was a stupid decision. But it is similar for any suicide, if one person fails exam or has loss in business or his true love rejects, dying is not a way out for us.
But for person involved, his life just has no meaning and is just pain.

From character Gaurav's perpective, he lost reason for living. Since the start of movie, he was shown having this obsession for Aryan.